# npm install error ( npm install -g angular-cli ) in windows 7

Tags: npm, angular-cli

Could you please help me on this issue,

when i am trying to install Angular 4 Cli in my system ,we'r getting error messages.please follow the below attached error link.

[image]

Comment: The title, the text, and the screenshot are all contradictory. What do you really want to do? Install an obsolete version of the CLI globally (as the title say), install the CLI for Angular 4 (as the text says), or install, locally, a number of future versions of angular packages?

Comment: I think you have installed node as admin, so you need to uninstall angular cli first and then install it as admin

Comment: i tried with freshly re-installation but getting same error again

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the package-lock.json file. My guess is you're downloading from a proxy?

Try `npm install packages... --no-package-lock` the key being `--no-package-lock`

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Node.js and Angular CLI can be setup on Windows 7 in few simple steps:

Step 1: Download Node.js

Download the latest release of Node.js from: Nodejs downloads page. I have downloaded Node.js for Windows 64-bit and the filename is: node-v8.9.3-x64.msi

Step 2: Install Node.js for Windows.

In Windows Explorer, locate the downloaded Nodejs .msi file. Double-click the .msi file. A set of screens will appear to guide you through the installation process. This will install Node.js and Node Package Manager (NPM) on your machine.

Step 3: Verify Node.js Installation

Type the following commands to check the versions of Node.js and NPM

`node -v`

`npm -v`

Step 4: Install Angular CLI

Angular Command Line Interface (CLI) is the easiest way to create new Angular projects. Execute the following NPM command to install Angular CLI:

`npm install @angular/cli -g`

After this installation, the CLI tool can be accessed by using ng commands.

Step 5: Verify Angular CLI

Type the command:

`ng -v`

I hope this helps.